# User authentication, doesn't recognize cyrillic characters

Tags: php

I am having a problem with inserting a username and password in a login system using cyrillic characters.

The password is decoded as SHA1, when i create a user with cyrillic characters it doesn't work for me!

Can you tell me if i need to insert something special in it?

code:

```
<?php
define(DOC_ROOT,dirname(__FILE__)); // To properly get the config.php file
$username = $_POST['username']; //Set UserName
$password = $_POST['password']; //Set Password
$msg ='';
if(isset($username, $password)) {
ob_start();
include(DOC_ROOT.'/config.php'); //Initiate the MySQL connection
// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($username);
$mypassword = stripslashes($password);
$myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbC, $myusername);
$mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbC, $mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM login_subadmin WHERE user_name='$myusername' and user_pass=SHA1('$mypassword')";
$result=mysqli_query($dbC, $sql);
// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "admin.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword");

header("location:index.php");
}
else {
$msg = "Wrong Username or Password. Please retry";
header("location:login.php?msg=$msg");
}
ob_end_flush();
}
else {
header("location:login.php?msg=Please enter some username and password");
}
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: do you have any `code` to show?

Comment: What kind of database are you storing this information in?  Is it formatted to accept cyrillic?

Comment: I edited my code, the database i use accepts cyrillic characters, i mean i am able to print cyrillic characters but it takes strange characters in the password field in the database after sha1

Comment: are you sure that everything is UTF-8 encoded? Including the form where username and password come from?

Comment: Yeah... i added my whole code.. still nothing working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to set your database and code + header to handle the page as UTF-8. It has to be the same charset all over the page. You could also use PHP's hash function for SHA1.

**Example code:**

```
<?php
$myUsername=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password=$_POST['password'];
$msg="";

if(isset($username, $password))
{
    ob_start();
    include(DOC_ROOT.'/config.php'); //Initiate the MySQL connection

    $password=sha1($password);
    $result=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `login_subadmin` WHERE user_name='$myUsername' AND `user_pass`='$password'", $sql);

    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
}
?>
```

Remember that the hash might get different results when using mysqli_real_escape_string(); in the password hash. If you already hash:ed passwords, just escape the password before you hash it.

Comment: Hey thanks, but, what do you mean by use php's function for sha1?

Comment: Done, I've added the code now. EDIT: Please use my new code. There was a wrong variable in it.

Comment: There was a wrong variable in my code. Please use the updated one!

Comment: Use my updated code please. The other one had a few wrong variables.